# question about bounds checking inside standard containers

Tags: c++, indexoutofboundsexception, stdarray

i have written a function that returns the data at an index for a simple implementation of an array type similar to `std::array`.

```
constexpr const T& at(size_t index) const
{
  if(index < Size)
    return data_[index];
  throw std::out_of_range ("Index out of range");
}
```

Where `Size` is a template argument.

my question is about passing in a negative index let's say: `array.at(-1)`

this also throws an index out of bound exception even though there is no check for the particular case where the index is a negative value. why is this handled automatically? i am confused.

Comment: When doing `size_t var = -1;` - what do you think the value of `var` is?

Comment: The `size_t` type is **unsigned** so you can't actually pass `-1`. It will be converted to `UINT_MAX` (or something similar).

Comment: @AdrianMole thank you. so it gets converted, now it makes sense

Comment: @KamilCuk as already mentioned, now i know it will get converted to an unsigned int value so that's why it works out the box, thanks for raising the question

Comment: Different point: Be careful when building containers from scratch. Often it is easier and safer to derive from an existing standard container type or have your class having a standard container as a (private) member, only adding your special stuff and using the other functionality for free from the standard.

Comment: @SKCoder I don't think deriving from an standard container is "easy" to get right

Comment: @SKCoder i'm not planning to use them in any actual application, i'm just trying to understand the inner workings better.

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned integral type.   When a (signed) integral value of `-1` is converted to an unsigned integral type, the result is the maximum value that `size_t` can represent.   Which means that `Size > index` is always true unless `Size` holds a greater value than a `size_t` can  (which would also mean that the type of `Size` must be able to represent a larger set of values than a `size_t`)

Comment: @AdrianMole it's `SIZE_MAX`, not `UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score -3):

As per [Adrian Mole's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62994058/question-about-bounds-checking-inside-standard-containers/62994460#)
the size_t type is unsigned so you can't actually pass -1. It will be converted to UINT_MAX (or something similar).

Comment: It will be converted to `SIZE_MAX`, not  `UINT_MAX`.

Comment: Since your answer is verbatim of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62994058/question-about-bounds-checking-inside-standard-containers/62994460#comment111397188_62994058) I advise you to read about [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)